# Can I mention tech stack in Employment Reference Letter for "Software engineer"?

Tags: human-resources, software-development, references, recommendation-letter, referral

Can I mention tech stack in the "Roles and Responsibilities" part of the reference letter ?. "Employment Reference Letter" is required for Visa/PR/New Job. And Letter looks something like this

> During his tenure as Software Engineer he performed the following duties:
>
> - Area: Software Development, Quality assurance and Support.
> - Technology: JavaScript, Node.js, MongoDB, Docker, Redis.
>
>   1. Providing support and guidance in application services operations.
>   2. Writing, updating and maintaining code in JavaScript/Node.js programming language, within the implemented framework as per system requirements.
>   3. .......... so on

Comment: @JoeStrazzere  Yes, he has asked to include tech stack.

Comment: If you don't know what level of detail to include, you should ask your manager. Some companies like to keep details of their tech stack to be private.

Answer (score 1):

You can mention whatever you like as long as:

> a) It's relevant (and preferably positive) to the job he's applying for
>
> b) It's the truth

Lots of job roles include stuff that's outside of the general/generic job description but that can be a positive thing.